# DYNAMIC SQL RETURNING clause giving error in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Below is the anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
v_tablename VARCHAR2(20);
sql_statement VARCHAR2(500);
v_empid emp.emp_id%TYPE := 11;
v_empname emp.emp_name%TYPE;
v_deptid emp.dept_id%TYPE;
v_age emp.age%TYPE;
v_sex emp.sex%TYPE;
BEGIN
v_tablename := '&table';
sql_statement := 'UPDATE ' || v_tablename || ' SET age = age + 1 WHERE emp_id = :1 RETURNING empname,deptid,age,sex INTO :2, :3, :4, :5';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statement USING v_empid RETURNING INTO v_empname, v_deptid, v_age, v_sex;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || v_empname);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dept Id: ' || v_deptid);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Age: ' || v_age);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sex: ' || v_sex);
END;
```

When I execute this, I am getting the below error message:

```
ORA-00904: "DEPTID": invalid identifier
```

The error is thrown in the below line:

```
sql_statement := 'UPDATE ' || v_tablename || ' SET age = age + 1 WHERE emp_id = :1 RETURNING empname,deptid,age,sex INTO :2, :3, :4, :5';
```

The error sounds like the variable is not already declared but for `RETURNING` in a DML (i.e. `UPDATE` in my case) do we really need to declare the variables?

Kindly let me know how to resolve this and make this piece of block work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `returning` clause is attempting to return columns `empname` and `deptid`, when the columns in the table are `emp_name` and `dept_id`. It isn't the local variables names that are the problem, or mentioned in the error message.

So you need:

```
... RETURNING emp_id, dept_id, age, sex INTO ...
```

I'm not sure why you've dropped the underscores in your local variable names; it might be less confusing if you had `v_emp_id`, `v_emp_name` and `v_dept_id`.

Of course this doesn't need to be done with dynamic SQL anyway, but I assume you're experimenting.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution...my misconception lead me to this issue. Yes correct, I am new to DYNAMIC SQL and experimenting with it.